# Open source EDIFACT BAPLIE parser in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, edifact

How I can read EDIFACT BAPLIE file in C# or VB.NET?

Is there any Open Source to read EDIFACT BAPLIE file in .NET?

Comment: EDIFACT is just text.  Learn what the delimiters are and parse it.  EDIDEV has a collection of (not free) tools, and there are hundreds of commercial EDI translators that will give you a scaled solution.  Go find EDI Notepad and download it to learn what your BAPLIE file is, and then you can write your own wheel..i mean parser.

Answer (score 2):

There are many open-source EDI translator solutions out there, and of course the world famous [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11278/EDIFACT-to-XML-to-Anything-You-Want), written by Tonster, which is a great C# parser to XML. Well written and it explains the segments and how they are made up.
Of course you will need to understand what [EDI is](https://searcherp.techtarget.com/definition/EDIFACT) in the first place, and know what **you want** out of the messages.

EDI is not a file type like CSV, XML, etc. It's a standard messaging construct that is used and has been used in various industries since the 1970s.

BAPLIE is one of over **[200 templates](http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d08a/trmd/baplie_c.htm)** that fits the EDIFACT standard, and so you will need to cater for it specifically, allowing for variations in the standard. Not all message providers give you a clean EDI file/message that fits the standard. Some segments could be in the wrong order, for example! But it's still a "valid" EDI file.

Anyway, without too much on the history and the "do's and don'ts", I suggest you search for EDIFACT parsers on Google and in particular the EDI parsers on GitHub. I use ETASOFT's [XTranslator](http://www.xtranslator.com/), as it gives a visual mapping tool to convert EDI files (or any type of file) to any format, including directly feeding into an SQL Server database. It also comes with a C# API library, which is handy. The product is not free, but it's very well priced compared to other alternatives.

The other alternative, is for you to consider the services of a B2B expert (consultants), that specialise in setting and configuring systems and processes for effective B2B communications, including EDI. And, then there is also **Blockchain**, which is another level again!

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11278/EDIFACT-to-XML-to-Anything-You-Want) describes an EDIFACT to XML converter in c#. From there you can take the created XML and use it for whatever you need. You could of course parse the EDIFACT file yourself, but the format is a bit awkward and dated and the .Net framework doesn't have any tools to help you with parsing EDIFACT files. Therefore the detour through XML is probably the easiest way.

Regarding the BAPLIE message type, you can find the specifications for the EDIFACT standard you need to parse on the [UNECE-Website](http://www.unece.org/tradewelcome/areas-of-work/un-centre-for-trade-facilitation-and-e-business-uncefact/outputs/standards/unedifact.html). There are also companies like [Truugo](http://www.truugo.com/edifact/) who offer an easy to use service for discovering and browsing EDIFACT standards.

Comment: Sir Is any free or paid  component that help me to parse edifact baplie file in dot net????